How to get Shimmer L1 address from the given Shimmer L2 (EVM) address?
I've started developing my app on Shimmer EVM and now I need some SMR for my account. I've added my L2 address to MetaMask and I have some SMR in my BitFinex wallet. However, when I tried to withdraw SMR from BitFinex, it requires an L1 address instead of the EVM address. How can I find out my L1 address from the existing L2 address in MetaMask?
Thanks

I don't think such an address exists. While the ShimmerEVM network has a Shimmer L1 address, when just sending funds to it from an exchange, they will not appear in any L2 address you own. I'd use a wallet that supports both Shimmer and ShimmerEVM (e.g. Firefly or Bloom), create a L1 address there, receive the funds, and transfer them to L2.
